# How to convert timestamp to pandas to_datetime?

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, string-to-datetime

I do realize this has already been addressed here. Nevertheless, I hope this question was different.

I have a `dataframe` with timestamp with dtype as `object`.

```
sample = {"Timestamp" : ["2021-03-19-17.03.19.149168", "2021-02-26-17.03.40.062637",
                         "2021-02-26-17.00.35.580631", "2021-06-09-18.03.38.497239", 
                         "2021-06-09-18.03.38.497239"]}

test = pd.DataFrame(sample)
```

I'm trying to convert the object type to pandas `datetime`,

```
test["Timestamp"] = pd.to_datetime(test["Timestamp"], 
                                   format="%Y-%m-%d-%H.%M.%S.%Z",
                                   errors="coerce")
```

Using the above code returns

```
    Timestamp
0   NaT
1   NaT
2   NaT
3   NaT
4   NaT
```

How to convert the above timestamp to pandas `datetime` type?

Comment: Pandas is pretty smart, if you don't care much about performance, you can just do pd.to_datetime(test['Timestamp'], errors='coerce')`.

Comment: @QuangHoang This won't work with OP's example because of the dots. On pandas 1.1.5 without coercion to NaT: `ParserError: Unknown string format: 2021-03-19-17.03.19.149168`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your format is incorrect, you are using `%Z` (timezone) instead of `%f` (microseconds). The latter works as expected:

```py
>>> pd.to_datetime(test["Timestamp"], format="%Y-%m-%d-%H.%M.%S.%f")

0   2021-03-19 17:03:19.149168
1   2021-02-26 17:03:40.062637
2   2021-02-26 17:00:35.580631
3   2021-06-09 18:03:38.497239
4   2021-06-09 18:03:38.497239
Name: Timestamp, dtype: datetime64[ns]
```